# conv2d in custom Keras loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to implement a custom loss function in Keras with TF backend based on the Laplacian of two images.

```
def blur_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    #weighting of blur loss
    alpha = 1
    mae = losses.mean_absolute_error(y_true, y_pred)
    lapKernel = K.constant([0, 1, 0, 1, -4, 1, 0, 1, 0],shape = [3, 3])

    trueLap = K.conv2d(y_true, lapKernel)
    predLap = K.conv2d(y_pred, lapKernel)
    trueBlur = K.var(trueLap)
    predBlur = K.var(predLap)
    blurLoss = alpha * K.abs(trueBlur - predBlur)
    loss = (1-alpha) * mae + alpha * blurLoss
    return loss
```

When I try to compile the model I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kitti_train.py", line 65, in <module>
    model.compile(loss='mean_absolute_error', optimizer='adam', metrics=[blur_loss])
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/dl4cv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 924, in compile
    handle_metrics(output_metrics)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/dl4cv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 921, in handle_metrics
    mask=masks[i])
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/dl4cv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 450, in weighted
    score_array = fn(y_true, y_pred)
  File "/home/ubuntu/prednet/blur_loss.py", line 14, in blur_loss
    trueLap = K.conv2d(y_true, lapKernel)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/dl4cv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 3164, in conv2d
    data_format='NHWC')
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/dl4cv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 655, in convolution
    num_spatial_dims, strides, dilation_rate)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/dl4cv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 483, in _get_strides_and_dilation_rate
    (len(dilation_rate), num_spatial_dims))
ValueError: len(dilation_rate)=2 but should be 0
```

After reading other questions, my understanding is that this problem stems from the compilation using placeholder tensors for y_true and y_pred. I've tried checking if the inputs are placeholders and replacing them with zero tensors, but this gives me other errors.

How do I use a convolution (the image processing function, not a layer) in my loss function without getting these errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here was a misunderstanding of the conv2d function which is not simply a 2-dimensional convolution. It is a batched 2-d convolution of multiple channels. So while you might expect a *2d function to accept 2-dimensional tensors, the input should actually 4 dimensions (batch_size, height, width, channels) and the filter should also be 4 dimensions (filter_height, filter_width, input_channels, output_channels). Details can be found in the [TF docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d)

Comment: So, what did you replace the Conv2D with to make it work?

Comment: I still used Conv2D, but made the inputs 4D. e.g. `lapKernel = K.constant([0, 1, 0, 1, -4, 1, 0, 1, 0],shape = [3, 3, 1, 1])`